# VCC of an IC (particularly UC3843)

Tags: voltage, capacitor, vcc, load-regulation

So I am recreating this load regulation circuit using a buck converter and UC3843 on PSIM[image]
but instead of using the UC3843 as a ready-made element, I constructed the circuit of UC3843 based on this:[image] Now one point I am confused about is that the VCC voltage probe in my target circuit shows a decrease in voltage (going into VCC):

[image].

However, in the circuit I have created, which is constructed based on the same values as my desired circuit, the VCC is showing an increase in voltage:
[image: This is the VCC part of the circuit]  [image: graph shows an increasing voltage]

Why is this the case in here particularly? The values are almost all identical.
My only doubt is that a VCC in an IC is not just a voltage input point, but could be consisting of other components/elements as well...?

Here is the VC drawing from VCC:

[image]

Comment: Where are you simulating the schematic(s)?

Comment: Apart from your main problem, I see that you are trying to drive the MOSFET with ground-referenced OUT signal, so it won't be sufficient to turn the MOSFET on. You should use a level-shifter to "translate" the ground-referenced OUT signal to a source-referenced signal.

Comment: Are all Ⓐ and ⓥ just measurement probes? I would normally think of those symbols as sources...

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes. They're just measurement probes.

Comment: @ChristianidisVasileios PSIM software

Comment: @RohatKılıç can you elaborate a bit more? My design is mainly based on the functional block diagram that I provided above.

Comment: So to summarize, your concern is: with the stock model, you see VCC decreasing; with your constructed model, you see VCC increasing?  Is that it?  It seems your model doesn't represent VCC draw (output currents and internal consumption), so the voltage is rising to the 21.65V voltage divider setting, and this should be at a time constant of 17ms. Is that correct?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes that's my concern. As for the model not representing VCC draw, I would be grateful to suggestions on how I can modify it to represent it properly.

Comment: Well, the Vc pin (output driver supply) obviously needs to draw from it, unclear if you've done that already. COMP op-amp can source current to a pin, which must come from Vcc.  Ref obviously is a pass device from Vcc to Vref. And the internal logic can be represented with a dependent current source, as a function of Vcc and Tj. Notice it varies with UVLO, e.g. https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/uc3842a-d.pdf Fig.17 (which does not describe temperature dependence unfortunately).

Comment: @TimWilliams I added another image to the post to demonstrate the VC pin drawing from VCC. However, the link that you shared represents the UC3843 developed by ON, which is quite different from the one developed by TI. VRef is just supposed to be 5V actually. I am unsure about the other points that you mentioned.